# What to do about ties in the photo contest?

Tags: discussion, contest

So, what *should* we do if there's a tie in the contest at the time the winner is selected?

(Vote for your preference, or add your own solution.)

Comment: And I suppose, in the spirit of the thing, we should go with the top answer _here_ at the time of any tie. We'll have to open a new thread for what to do about ties in _this_ vote, though. :)

Answer (score 17):

### Option 4

Photo submitted last wins (on the principle that if it garnered the same number of votes over a shorter period of time, people had a stronger "like" reaction to it).

Answer (score 4):

### Option 1

Photo submitted first wins. (The other one can, of course, win the next week, with the same advantage over newer contestants.)

Answer (score 1):

### Option 2

Moderator picks. (This was, effectively, the previous tie resolution mechanism.)

Comment: Could be boosted with "objective checklist": 1. Originality  (not landscape > landscape , haha) 2. technique (sharpness, noise, composition, exposure - e.g. the new "golden morning" landscape has totally blows red parts, and is more red morning than golden morning).

Answer (score 1):

Check for downvotes on the images (forbidden in theory, but happens in practice), and remove them from the count. If it's still a tie after that, move to the next option in the list.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 3

Flip a coin.

Answer (score -1):

## Option 5

Both photos run in consecutive weeks and next update is delayed a week

Comment: This could lead to the photo *never* changing (if the tie is never broken).